# элементы в RowBuilder если большое количество то начинает тормозить, как это исправить?

Tags: flutter, dart

использую кастомный `Row` с `builder`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RowBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  final IndexedWidgetBuilder itemBuilder;
  final MainAxisAlignment mainAxisAlignment;
  final MainAxisSize mainAxisSize;
  final CrossAxisAlignment crossAxisAlignment;
  final TextDirection textDirection;
  final VerticalDirection verticalDirection;
  final int itemCount;
  const RowBuilder({
    Key key,
    @required this.itemBuilder,
    @required this.itemCount,
    this.mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    this.mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    this.crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    this.textDirection,
    this.verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: mainAxisAlignment,
      children: new List.generate(
          this.itemCount, (index) => this.itemBuilder(context, index)).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

для дальнейшего использования внутри `SingleChildCcrollView` или `Expanded`(мне нужно прописать на подобии `ListView.builder` но без возможности прокрутки и чтобы все элементы поместились внутри родительского виджета) в приложении:

```
RowBuilder(
     itemCount: list.length,
     itemBuilder: (context, index){
        return Text('Text: ${index}');
})
```

но при большом объеме элементов начинает тормозить приложение, как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

А такой способ чем вам не подошел?

```
ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemCount: 10000,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Text('Text: $index');
  },
),
```

Не уверен что, что-то поменялось:

```
class RowBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  final IndexedWidgetBuilder itemBuilder;
  final MainAxisAlignment mainAxisAlignment;
  final MainAxisSize mainAxisSize;
  final CrossAxisAlignment crossAxisAlignment;
  final TextDirection textDirection;
  final VerticalDirection verticalDirection;
  final int itemCount;
  const RowBuilder({
    Key key,
    @required this.itemBuilder,
    @required this.itemCount,
    this.mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    this.mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    this.crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    this.textDirection,
    this.verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: mainAxisAlignment,
      children: [
        for (int i = 0; i < this.itemCount; i++) this.itemBuilder(context, i),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: просто RowBuilder растягивает родительский виджет, а ListView.builder работает немного не так, он берет размер родительского виджета как есть и размещает элементы с использованием прокрутки